# Interchanging the summation $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{2i} f(i,j)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is there any method to interchange the summation $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{2i} f(i,j)$ when the upper bound of inner sum is a function of $i$, i.e. 2i, I have no idea to deal with this situation.

I have tried to read some posts on MSE, but still don't have any good ideas. Any ideas would be very welcome.

Comment: Your sum is taken over all pairs (i, j) such that $j\le 2i$.  This restriction is equivalent to $i\ge [(j + 1)/2]$, hence you get$$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 1}^{2i} f(i,j) = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{i = [(j + 1)/2]}^{\infty}f(i,j)$$.

Comment: I got the point on how to deal with this now. Thank you.

Comment: Posted the same text as an answer, accept and close the question.

Comment: The sum is $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}I(j \leq 2i)f(i,  j)$

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is taken over all pairs $(i, j)$ such that $j\le 2i$. This restriction is equivalent to $i\ge [(j+1)/2]$, hence you get
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 1}^{2i} f(i,j) = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{i = \left[{j + 1/2}\right]}^{\infty}f(i,j).
$$

Comment: If $f(i, j) = (-1)^{j}$, then the sum on the left is $0$ and the sum on the right diverges. You'll need [Fubini-Tonelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) to switch the order of the sums.